# When debugging how do we know the frame of a UIView or how is it stored?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Take a look at the picture below

[image]

I am looking for UIView and I cannot find this so called _frame struct.

How internally exactly apple store a UIView frame? And what would be the easiest way to find that out during debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UIView` doesn't store its frame; it just returns its layer's frame.

A `CALayer` doesn't store its frame either.  When you ask a layer for its frame, the layer computes the frame based on the layer's `bounds`, `position`, `anchorPoint`, and `transform`.  (Possibly it caches the computed `frame`, but if you disassemble the `-[CALayer frame]` method you will find code for computing it from the other properties.)

And a `CALayer` doesn't store any of those properties in instance variables.  Instead, it has a pointer to a `CA::Layer` instance, which is a private C++ object.  That C++ object stores the layer's properties.  The `view->_layer->_attr.layer` field is the pointer to the private `CA::Layer` instance.

If you want to see a view's frame in the debugger, you have to send it a message.  You can ask it for its description:

```
po _topBubble
```

Or you can ask it for its frame:

```
p (CGRect)[_topBubble frame]
```

Comment: very enlightening, a quick question: how would you disassemble the -[CALayer frame] method to learn more about how it is computed from other properties?

Comment: I used [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/) on the iPhone simulator's QuartzCore library.

Comment: Wow? p (CGRect)[_topBubble frame] works? Oh it works for all structs right? p is for structs and po is for objects.